# symfony2 fosUserbundle input type with bootstrap

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, widget, fosuserbundle

I'm quite new to symfony2, i have managed to implement fosUserBundle and Braincrafted bootstrap bundle.

I am trying to style the registration form to use boot strap and the inputs with `input-sm` class

the username and email are displaying as input-sm but the 2 password fields refuse to resize to the class i have applied.

is there somewhere in the fosUserbundle where the password field widget is configured

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

    {{ form_start(form, { 'style': 'horizontal', 'col_size': 'xs', 'label_col': 5, 'widget_col': 7, attr: {class: 'pull-left'}}) }}
    {{ form_row(form.username, { attr: {class: 'input-sm'}}) }}
    {{ form_row(form.email, { attr: {class: 'input-sm'}}) }}
    {{ form_row(form.plainPassword, { attr: {class: 'input-sm'}}) }}
    {{ form_row(form.plainPassword.second, { attr: {class: 'input-sm'}}) }}
    <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input class="btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}" />
    </div>
    {{ form_rest(form) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

FosUserBundle or not, you can overwrite Twig form rendering directly to achieve this, have a look at [How to customize form rendering](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) in SF cookbook.

Basically you can either get more precise in your template by splitting form_row into labels, widgets and errors to target the input ("form_widget" below) more specifically and apply the correct classes :

```
{{ form_errors(form.plainPassword) }}
{{ form_label(form.plainPassword) }}
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword) }}
```

You can also generate your own form style for desired type of input by decalring it directly in your template :

```
{% form_theme form _self %}
{% block integer_widget %}
     <div class="integer_widget">
         // Your custom layout
     </div>
{% endblock %}

{% Block body %}
    // Rendering your form, your custom layout will be used.
{% endblock %}
```

You can also declare it in a separate template if you want to use it somewhere else, refer to the above cookbook page to see how.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, i previously read up on customising the forms with twig from the book, in my sample code above it works for the first two fields, but the same customisation for the password fields using the same syntax don't seem to be picking up the class, i did also try defining them separately as labels/errors/widget and the password fields still get rendered without the 'input-sm' class.